# Exported image black with 0 value

Tags: python, java, arrays, python-3.x, google-earth-engine

I tried to use the following code but when exporting my map and I check my output data in arcmap. It is totally black and the value is 0.
I don't know what is wrong with my code.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/476db72426a67e03a604b6712ce97ef4?hl=ar

```
// The purpose of this script is to estimate sub-pixel fractions
// of identifiable spectral "endmembers".  This involves finding
// "pure" areas to estimate the endmembers, some matrix algebra
// followed by the mapping of the fractional cover.

// Use the reflective bands. 
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'];

// First, let's find a cloud free scene in our area of interest.
// Make a point using the geometry tools and name the import 'point'.
// Import Landsat 8 TOA data and name the collection 'l8'.
var image = ee.Image(l8
    .filterBounds(point)
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than', 2)
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2020,2020,'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(10,12,'month'))
    .first())
    .select(bands);
    
  print(image)
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.3}, 'image');

// Now, delineate polygons of 'pure' regions.  Click +New Layer for 
// each polygon.  Name the imports 'bare', 'vegetation' and 'water'.
// Get the mean spectrum in each of the endmember polygons.
var bareMean = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), bare, 30).values();
var waterMean = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), water, 30).values();
var vegMean = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), vegetation, 30).values();
var snowMean = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), snow, 30).values();

// Optional: plot the endmembers
print(ui.Chart.image.regions(image, ee.FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(bare, {label: 'bare'}), 
    ee.Feature(water, {label: 'water'}),
    ee.Feature(vegetation, {label: 'vegetation'}),
    ee.Feature(snow, {label: 'snow'})]), 
  ee.Reducer.mean(), 30, 'label', [0.48, 0.56, 0.65, 0.86, 1.61, 3.2]));

// Turn the endmember lists into an array that can be used in unmixing.
// Concatenate the lists along the 1-axis to make an array.
var endmembers = ee.Array.cat([bareMean, vegMean, waterMean, snowMean], 1);
//print(endmembers)

// Turn the image into an array image, in which each pixel has a 2-D matrix.
var arrayImage = image.toArray().toArray(1);

// Perform the unmixing in array space using the matrixSolve image method.  
// Note the need to cast the endmembers into an array image.
var unmixed = ee.Image(endmembers).matrixSolve(arrayImage);

// Convert the result from an array image back to a multi-band image.
var unmixedImage = unmixed.arrayProject([0])
    .arrayFlatten([['bare', 'veg', 'water', 'snow']]);

// Display the result.
Map.addLayer(unmixedImage, {}, 'fractions');

// Constrained:constraining the result to be non-negative and sum to one.
var constrained = image.unmix([bareMean, vegMean, waterMean, snowMean], true, true);
Map.addLayer(constrained, {}, 'constrained fractions');

//Export output to Google Drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: constrained,
  description: 'unmix',
  scale: 30,
  region: point,
  maxPixels: 1e9,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
});
```

Please guide me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only exporting a single pixel - the `region` is set to `point`. All bands are actually not 0, but whatever tool you're using to visualise the image will have problems picking a good stretch, giving you a black pixel.

You could for instance use `image.geometry()` instead of `pixel` in this case:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: constrained,
  description: 'unmix',
  scale: 3000,
  region: image.geometry(),
  maxPixels: 1e9,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It gives me the values 0 to 1 but I am wondering about the scale of 3000. It doesn't give me the image in actual Landsat resolution (30m). However, I need the fraction images in 500m resolution to compare with MDOIS products. Do you think is it acceptable if I export my images in 500m resolution?@DanielWiell

Comment: I just picked `3000` to speed up the export. You should be fine with both 30m and 500m.

Comment: I can get only the value 0 to 1 with a 500m scale, not with 30m. The scale of 30m gives me a value of -3 to 3 and the image looks strange.@DanielWiell

Comment: I don't see how that can be the case. I exported this at 500m, downloaded the result from Google Drive and drop it into QGIS. It's shows a pretty picture where the first bands are essentially stretched between 0 and 1. https://code.earthengine.google.com/dc66b1deec740c6e932d5dc60af6d9c5?hl=ar

Comment: Thank you very much. I can use the exported image at 500m. Could you please guide me on how I can change my code for an image collection? I am wondering how to change my code to apply to unmix method for images in one row and path or images in multiple rows and paths. Do you have any idea? Please help me to change my code for image collection. @DanielWiell

Comment: Write up a separate question for that. There's a lot of additional details you need to provide. Start with the final goal of your exercise - the output are you looking for. How you want to combine the imagery in the image collection etc.